# RxJava send onError() after 10secs

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm combining different operations in an `Android` app with`RxJava` and I want that either the flow finishes successfully and submits items in `onNext()` or that after 10seconds, an `onError` will be thrown.

I have tried something like this with `timeout`:

```
Observable.from(list)
            .doOnNext(new Action1<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<String> list) {
                    //do something here
                }
            })
            .filter(new Func1<List<String>>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<String> list) {
                    return list != null;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<String>>, Observable<MyResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<MyResponse> call(List<String> list) {
                    //flatmap something here
                    return Observable.just(new MyResponse(list));
                }

            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<MyResponse, Observable<AnotherResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<AnotherResponse> call(MyResponse myResponse) {
                    //do something here
                    return Observable.just(new AnotherResponse(myResponse));
                }
            })
            .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<AnotherResponse>()) {
                //do Subscription stuff here
            });
```

But this will throw a timeout in any case, I just want to jump to `onError` if the flow listed above has not finished successfully in 10seconds. Any suggestions how I could achieve this?

Comment: Basically `timeout` throws an error state, once the chain does not emit any item within your time limit. Basically I think your approach would work. Does your chain complete? if it does not complete then this might the reason, why timeout is executed.

Comment: @Christopher You're right, my chain does not complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Christopher said in his comment, the reason you are getting the error is that `timeout` will throw a `TimeoutException` whenever a non-finished Observable (`onCompleted` was not yet called) fails to produce the next `onNext` within the set timeout.

Since I am not sure what your source Observable - or rather, the Observables inside the `flatMap`s - are doing I would first check whether it should actually produce an `onCompleted` (probably after at least one `onNext`) or whether it stays open "by design" (it may be that the source is an open ended stream like the network state of your device). If the source itself is open-ended by design, you can artificially introduce an `onCompleted` after the first `onNext` by just adding `take(1)` to your chain.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you.

```
private Observable<String> myMethod(final List<String> list) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override public void call(final Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

            // Your long lasting operation
            Observable<String> listObservable = Observable.from(list);

            // This is just my way to make slow operation (I have 10 items in my list)
            Observable<String> delayedObservable = listObservable.zipWith(Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), new Func2<String,
                    Long,
                    String>() {
                @Override public String call(String s, Long aLong) {
                    return s;
                }
            });
            delayedObservable.subscribe(subscriber);

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    // This thread makes the timeout, it is up to you if you would keep this like this.
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    subscriber.onError(new TimeoutException());
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.start();
        }
    });
}
```

This worked for me, in a very basic situation, I hope it can help you.